# Docker on Windows Data Persistence - Host Mapping vs Data Volume

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm very new to Docker and after reading about data volumes I'm still somewhat confused by the behaviour I'm seeing.

In my compose file I had an entry for mysql like this:

```
db:
  image: mysql
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: p4ssw0rd!
  networks:
    - back
```

This mapped the /database directory to `/var/lib/mysql`.  The database files where created and I could start Wordpress, install, add a post.  The problem as it never persisted any created data. If I restarted Docker and executed:

`docker-compose up -d`

The database was empty.

Changing this to:

```
db:
  image: mysql
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: p4ssw0rd!
  networks:
    - back
```

And adding in a volume like this:

```
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Now persists the data in the Docker data volume and restarting works.  Any data created during the last run is still present.

How would I get this to work using the host mapped directory?

Am I right in thinking the second example using volumes is the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker volumes on windows work a bit different way than Linux. Basically on Windows, docker runs a VM and the docker is setup inside the VM. So it seems to you that you run docker commands locally on Windows but the actual stuff happens in background inside a VM.

```
docker run -v d:/data:/data alpine ls /data
```

First you need to make share the D: in docker settings. You can find a detailed article explaining the steps for doing so

https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c

Comment: Yeah, I had all the sharing the host drive working.  I could see all the files being loaded into the `\database` directory.  I was just confused as to why it seemed to over-write these files on each start.